# Multiple arrays in post__not_in parameter

Tags: exclude

Does the post__not_in parameter can have multiple arrays for excluding, for example, sticky posts and also the IDs of some other posts?

Something like:

```
'post__not_in' => array(
   get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
   array( 1, 2, 3 )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't. You'd just merge the arrays:

```
'post__not_in' => array(
    array_merge( get_option( 'sticky_posts' ), array( 1, 2, 3 ) ),
)
```

And just because someone else will mention it if I don't: [`post__not_in` has terrible performance](https://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/performance-improvements-by-removing-usage-of-post__not_in/) and you'd be better off finding an alternate solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggesting the alternative solution, i'll look into it.